# Alternative to Apple Books for power users that works across all devices?

Tags: ios, macos, ebooks, ipad-app

I'm quite sick of Apple Books as it randomly deletes books from my library on the iPad, and find myself out of a book exactly when I need it the most and I'm offline. The app also makes it deliberately hard to sync multiple books, one has to click each file one by one.

With Podcasts, I absolutely love Overcast over the default Podcasts app for the amount of control I get with downloading what I need and playing it in the order I need with an intuitive UI. Is there such an alternative for PDF & ePub files that can help me:

organise books into collections,
sync across all my devices (ideally over iCloud),
be available on all devices - macOS, iPadOS, iOS
Very happy to pay for such an app with these basic functionalities built in a way not to frustrate the user.

Comment: I'm not an Apple user, but as someone running an OPDS capable eBook server I've heard good things about Stanza in the past. Not sure if it fits your bill. But while waiting for recommendations, you might wish to take a look at it – and maybe at [this list](https://www.igeeksblog.com/best-ebook-reader-ipad-iphone-apps/). Good luck!

Comment: Nicely formatted list! Will take a look thanks.